# How to execute code only on posts older than 2 weeks

Tags: plugins

I am trying to modify a plugin to only execute on posts that are older than two weeks. I added the isOldEnough function below to try and do that. What am I missing, here?

```
function remove_metadata()

{
$isOldEnough = function ()
    {
        $postDate = strtotime( $post->post_date );
        $todaysDate = time();
        if($postDate - $todaysDate > 129600) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
 if ($isOldEnough) 
 {
        /* Register style css. */
        wp_enqueue_style( 'remove-style-meta', plugins_url( 'css/entrymetastyle.css', __FILE__ ), false, '1.0', 'all' );

}
}
add_action('wp_head', 'remove_metadata');
```

The plugin simply removes the metadata using a couple lines of CSS.

Right now it executes the code on all posts, regardless of post_date.

Comment: "Removes the metadata using CSS" ... wat? You can't remove data from a MySQL database using CSS. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Did you check the WP_Query date parameters?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a couple of things are out of order.

- First, I'd definitely make sure to declare the `$post` global
- It's also probably worth wrapping your logic in an `is_single()` and/or `is_singular()` checks
- Last, the section where you're calculating the time as greater than 2 weeks, the current time and post date are switched. This works for me:

```php
/**
 * Enqueue a stylesheet for posts older than two weeks.
 */
function hide_meta_for_older_posts() {
    if ( is_single() || is_singular() ) {
        global $post;

        if ( time() - strtotime( $post->post_date ) > ( 2 * WEEK_IN_SECONDS ) ) {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'remove-style-meta', plugins_url( 'css/entrymetastyle.css', __FILE__ ), false, '1.0', 'all' );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'hide_meta_for_older_posts' );
```